# Kernel of nonzero linear function in vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $l$ be a nonzero linear function on a vector space $V$, i.e. $l:V\to \mathbb{k}$. Show that $\text{ker}(l)$ is a maximal nontrivial linear subspace in $V$. Also prove that $V/\text{ker}(l)$ has dimension 1.

**Remark:** It is not necessary that $V$ is finite-dimensional space.

This is quite a famous problem and I was able to show that $\text{ker}(l)$ is maximal linear subspace of $V$. In other words, if $\text{ker}(l)\subseteq W\subseteq V$ then $W=\text{ker}(l)$ or $W=V$.

Also since $l$ is a nonzero it means that $\exists v\in V$ such that $l(v)\neq 0$. Then one can show that $V/\text{ker}(l)$ has a basis $v+\ker (l)$ which means that $V/ \ker(l)$ has dimension.

But I have spent some time and was not able to show that $\ker(l)$ is nontrivial subspace of $V$, which means that there is some element $x\neq 0\in V$ such that $l(x)=0$.

I think that this is wrong.

Anyway I would be very grateful if anyone can show how to prove or disprove it.

Comment: If $\dim(V)=1$, then $\mathrm{ker}(\ell)$ is trivial. So you won't be able to show the kernel is nontrivial unless you also know that $\dim(V)$ is not $1$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, exactly! This is what I was thinking. As you said if $\dim (V)=1$ then kernel is trivial. But if $\dim (V)>1$ then kernel is nontrivial.

Comment: If the dimension is greater than $1$, then pick a vector $x$ linearly independent from $v$. If $l(x)=0$, you are done. If $l(x)\neq 0$, then there exists $\lambda\neq 0$ such that $\lambda l(x) = l(v)$, so then $v-\lambda x$ lies in the kernel.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, sorry but how do you know that there is $\lambda \neq 0$ such that $\lambda l(x)=l(v)$? If I am not mistaken in order to conclude we should know smth about $l(v)$.

Comment: Because both $l(x)$ and $l(v)$ are elements of the field, and both nonzero, so $\lambda = \frac{l(v)}{l(x)}$ will do.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, Exactly! Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In a vector space of dimension $1$, a maximal subspace is trivial. To show it is nontrivial in dimension greater than one, simply take a one dimensional subspace as a counterexample to the containment condition.